# I can not see ipv4 and http, I can just see ipv6 and SSDP

Tags: http, ipv6, wireshark, ipv4

I have a real huge problem, when I am connected through the wireless of my university, I can just see adresses like this :

```
1823731 14856.287768        fe80::74b6:2d79:4343:41e1       ff02::c   SSDP          208 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
```

Here is a picture to understand more :

[http://data.imagup.com/12/1145300151.jpg http://data.imagup.com/12/1145300151.jpg](http://data.imagup.com/12/1145300151.jpg)

How Can I solve this problem ? Because I want to see the IP ADDRESS connected in the same wireless.
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

It almost looks like you are watching the wrong interface...

Comment: How ?
I think that those are the IPv6 Adresses ?
But Still I can not see the http urls, the cookie....

Comment: Those are link-local source addresses and link-local multicast destination addresses. You will see those on *any* link that has IPv6 enabled.